# How do I break a for loop inside of a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to make a lingo game, and me and my teacher are stymied on this section. We've tried just about everything so far, still no dice.

Basically, we're trying to check and see if the entry equals the randomly generated word, but the code seems to be skipping over this line, even if the conditions are met.

We think that it has to do with the code saving the enter keystroke after the user input's the entry, but we tried that and it still doesn't work. I think we may have to use a replace(), but I'm not sure.

We have tried:

.strip
.rstrip("\r\n")
Moving the conditional to the front and back, and even outside the loop.

```
chance = 0
print("Welcome to Lingo! You will have eight chances to guess the word.")

word = get_word()
print(word)
while(chance <= 8):
    chance += 1
    print()
    entry = input("Please enter a five letter word: ")


    for ltr in entry:
        place = word.find(ltr.lower())


        if(place < 0):
            print(ltr, sep ="", end ="")
        elif(entry[place] == word[place]): 
             print('[', ltr, ']', sep="", end="")
        else:
            print('(', ltr, ')', sep="", end="")
        if entry.rstrip("\r\n") == word:
            print("Good job, you guessed the word! Have a cookie! \ud83C")
            break       

    if chance == 8:
        print("You lose. Better luck next time.")
```

Comment: If you want to break the inner loop (the for loop) simply use the `break` statement.

Comment: Is your teacher really stymied by this? Really?

Answer (score 0):

To break the inner loop use the `break` statement or try the `pass` statement.

The `break` statement is used to exit out of a loop when an external condition is triggered.

The `pass` statement is used when an external condition is triggered and allows you to handle the condition without the loop being impacted in any way.

Comment: `pass` won't do anything. I'm not sure what you're referring to there.

Comment: The Python break statement immediately terminates a loop entirely. Program execution proceeds to the first statement following the loop body. Perhaps the `continue` statement, which would immediately terminate the current loop iteration.

Comment: Yes, I think you may mean `continue`. `pass` is just a placeholder; it doesn't actually do anything. Your description of `pass` is confusing though, so I'm not sure what you're intending.

Comment: I mean to say that `pass` indicates a null block, like you said, it can be used to quickly add things that are unimplemented.